# Routing to a tab from a button inside a modal in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I have a button inside a Ionic 4 Modal that I wish to when clicked have it open a page which is a tab.

I can verify that the tab exist because I have navigated to it directly.

Here is my code for the button itself:

```
<ion-button expand="block" class="signup" margin (click)="signupPage()">Don't have account? Sign Up</ion-button>
```

As you can see the click function loads upon clicking the button which activates this function here:

```
signupPage() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
    this.router.navigate([`/tabs/(signup:signup)`]);
  }
```

The modal closes however I am not routed to the tab and this is the error I am currently getting.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you have your route declared ?

Comment: yes it is declared and if I navigate to it directly by typing it in the url I can load the page.

Comment: So when you navigate to "tabs/signup" manually, it works well?

Comment: Well the actual route is "/tabs/(signup:signup)" so when I navigate to that it works well if I type it directly in the browser url. However it does not load from the function itself and gives that error I posted.

Comment: I don't get the `(signup:signup)` part? Are you assigning a variable there?

Comment: That is how you navigate to a tab and load into a tab

Comment: I've used Ionic for a long long time ago, I've been thinking in Angular logic, but Try 
 `this.router.navigate(["/tabs/signup"]);`

Comment: That is actually not how it is handled in Ionic 4 when using tabs.If I was navigating to a page by itself without the usage of tabs then /signup would work fine. However with tabs in ionic 4 the navigation is done by tab/(page:page) even in the url itself.

Comment: Are you using VSCode? If yes I can connect via LiveShare and take a look if you wish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186565/discussion-between-robert-and-westdabestdb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your markup and function as follows. You were supposed to change the tab route but you were using Angular router in order to change the route.

`[attr.href]` will add `href` attribute to `ion-button` element.

```
<ion-button expand="block" class="signup" margin [attr.href]="'/tabs/(signup:signup)'"  (click)="signupPage()">Don't have account? Sign Up</ion-button>

signupPage() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
    // you don't need to route from here anymore.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help! This solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

It can be also done in following way:

**On your button tap/click event:**

```
signupPage() {
  this.modalController.dismiss(dismissed: true,
    route: `/tabs/(signup:signup)`);
}
```

**And where you are presenting a modal, right before return await modal.present();**

```
 //According to your requirements

 //you can use this

 modal.onDidDismiss().then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data);
  if (result.data.route) {
    this.router.navigate([result.data.route]);
  }


 //or you can use this one
 modal.onDidDismiss().then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data);
  if (result.data.route) {
    this.router.navigate([result.data.route], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
    });
  }
});
```